# LastActivityDate different than LastLoginDate in ASPNET Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

In a ASPNET Membership provider implementation, the LastActivityDate is different than the LastLoginDate.
Which kind of information could be stored in this column if the user does not log in?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new user the LastLoginDate and the LastActivityDate is equal to the CreationDate.

The [LastLoginDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastlogindate.aspx) is updated when the method "ValidateUser" is called.
In most cases this will be at login.

The [LastActivityDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastactivitydate.aspx) is also updated when the method "ValidateUser" is called but also when information from the profile is requested.

So in that last case it can happens that when you have for example a backendpage with a list of all users including some profile information that you will see that the LastActivityDate is the same for all the users.  The LastActivityDate will then be set to the date and time you access the backendpage.

Comment: LastActivityDate is updated only when the Authentication is successful not when ValidateUser method gets called.